# question on C# data type

Tags: c#, types, c#-2.0

Did `Binary` and `ASCII` data type had been defined in C# 2.0?

I plan to detect several variables are Binary or ASCII or Integer(sbyte, byte, short, ushort, long, ulong) types.

I can use `typeof(sbyte)` ect.

But I failed to implement as this `typeof(binary)` or `typeof(ascii)`.
What I need is something like this typeof function to detect the variables are Binary or ASCII type?

[update]

```
           format code    Octal
Binary         001000      10
ASCII          010000      20
```

Comment: There is no Binary Or Ascii type in .NET. What type your variables are going to be?

Comment: How about explaining your problem at a higher level?  A good link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx

Comment: My variable is an string currently. I need validate its type bye several select case statement.

Comment: Are you trying to convert unknown data into a fitting datatype or are you having problem represent binary and/or ascii?

Comment: @stefan, Yes, I need try to convert unkonw data into a fitting datatype. I updated my original post.

Comment: Hmm... question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779695 sounds very similar, but posted by a different user. It seems unlikely to be a coincidence. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would store text data in a string, and binary data in a `byte[]`. **Do not try to store binary data in a string by applying an arbitrary encoding.** For example, if you try to use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binaryData)` then it's highly likely that you won't be able to get the original data back again.

If you need to store binary data in a string, you should use something like `Convert.ToBase64String` (and then `Convert.FromBase64String`) which stores 3 bytes of binary data in each 4 characters in the string.

If you need to store data in a string *and* the type of the original data, you should either store the type separately, or keep a compound form such as "type:data". Sample strings might then be:

```
int:10
string:10 // The digits 1 and 0, but originally as text, not a number
binary:hFed234= // Base-64-encoded data
```

Comment: Actually my variable already transferred to my validateFunction(string myVariable). (as this form). Then I must trypase the unknown variable and find it's data type.

Comment: @Nano HE: Then you have no hope of accurately recovering the original type - "10" can represent the number ten, or just two digits... and if binary data *is* passed to you, do you know how it's encoded into text?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and reply. I don't got idea of the encoded rule. That means,And I will the ValidateFun(EnumTypes aType, string myVariable) can be design as this form. I need to validate `myVariable` is `aType` (`EnumTypes.ASCII`.   Or `EnumTypes.Binary`). Then return true or false.

Comment: @Nano HE: If you don't now how the data is encoded, there's absolutely no way of retrieving it. The design basically seems a mess - I would do everything you possibly can to change it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=VS.80).aspx) and [System.Text.Decoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoder(v=VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to attempt-parse it into a fitting datatype. Set them up with priority.

Something like:

```
1) Try to parse integer, if fail continue
2) Try to parse text, if fail continue
3) Save binary
```

To autodetect encoding see [Determine a string's encoding in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025332/determine-a-strings-encoding-in-c)